# How to import a local library with cffi

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-cffi

i have a test.c like below (in the same dir as the python file)

```
#include <stdio.h>
void myprint();  
void myprint()
{
printf("hi\n");
}
```

and now i want to "import" it into my python script

```
from cffi import FFI
ffi = FFI()
ffi.cdef("void myprint();")
C = ffi.verify("""
#include "test.c"
""")
```

Using the examples from the cffi docs work fine.

Sorry for the large traceback error...

```
__pycache__/_cffi__xd52cd3eax2b8a27ce.c:185:18: fatal error: test.c: No such file or directory
 #include "test.c"
                  ^
compilation terminated.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/unixccompiler.py", line 116, in _compile
    extra_postargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 909, in spawn
    spawn(cmd, dry_run=self.dry_run)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/spawn.py", line 36, in spawn
    _spawn_posix(cmd, search_path, dry_run=dry_run)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/spawn.py", line 162, in _spawn_posix
    % (cmd, exit_status))
distutils.errors.DistutilsExecError: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/cffi/ffiplatform.py", line 48, in _build
    dist.run_command('build_ext')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 348, in run
    self.build_extensions()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 457, in build_extensions
    self.build_extension(ext)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 512, in build_extension
    depends=ext.depends)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 574, in compile
    self._compile(obj, src, ext, cc_args, extra_postargs, pp_opts)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/unixccompiler.py", line 118, in _compile
    raise CompileError(msg)
distutils.errors.CompileError: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pynfc_nfx.py", line 11, in <module>
    """)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/cffi/api.py", line 340, in verify
    lib = self.verifier.load_library()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/cffi/verifier.py", line 74, in load_library
    self._compile_module()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/cffi/verifier.py", line 139, in _compile_module
    outputfilename = ffiplatform.compile(tmpdir, self.get_extension())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/cffi/ffiplatform.py", line 25, in compile
    outputfilename = _build(tmpdir, ext)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/cffi/ffiplatform.py", line 51, in _build
    raise VerificationError('%s: %s' % (e.__class__.__name__, e))
cffi.ffiplatform.VerificationError: CompileError: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: Do you have python-dev package installed?

Comment: @aberna yes, i can run the demo scripts from the cffi docs no problem, there are exmaples using #include <stdio.h> which work fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fatal error: test.c: No such file or directory`

Try `ffi.verify(..., include_dirs=['.'])`.  The compiler is not called from the current directory, but instead from some temporary directory where cffi creates its temporary files.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the semicolon after `printf("hi")`.  (You also forgot `#include <stdio.h>` and probably a `\n` after `hi` but these should not give you compilation errors.)

Comment: Please show all the errors (in particular, the ones reported by the C compiler).